# Axis adjusting of an autocorrelation plot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create my autocorrelation function, because I don't have the Econometrics toolbox and I have succesfully created my function, but I can't get the x-axis in the stem-plot correct. The following picture will higlight my point:

[image]

As you can see in the picture there should be 4 where there is now 5. How can adjust the x-axis so that 5 will "jump" one step forward and so on...

Thank you for any help =)

EDIT:

Here is the code which generates this plot:

```
h = stem(corrVals, 'fill');
set(h,'MarkerFaceColor','red')
axis([1 25 -0.5 1.5])
```

Variable `corrVals` is a vector consisting of the autocorrelation values.
`corrVals(1)` is the autocorrelation at lag 0, `corrVals(2)` is the autocorrelation at lag 1 and so on...

Comment: What is the code to generate this plot?

Comment: I added the code to post =)

Comment: How about `h = stem(0:numel(corrVals)-1, corrVals, 'fill');` and then obviously don't make you axis start from `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the x-values for `stem`:

```
h = stem(0:length(corrVals) - 1, corrVals, 'fill');
```

Comment: And don't forget to change `axis([1 25 ...` to start from `0` if you want to see the whole plot. Oh but I guess maybe you don't care about the point at 0 because it will always be `1`

Comment: @Dan good point, but as you said: maybe point 0 is deliberately left out of the plot.

Comment: Thank you for advices! Did the job =)